# Spyder IDE automatic indentation

Tags: python, spyder

Is there any shortcut to automatically indent marked lines in the editor? For example, in MATLAB there is the CTRL+I shortcut.

Comment: Try **Wing IDE**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Matlab's syntax can match the opening closing statements of `if`,`while`, `for` etc. by looking for `end` statements.

In Python these are ambiguous and defined as the nested indentetation. Hence this cannot be reliably implemented as you cannot decide whether the succeeding `if` block belongs the the current `for` loop or it is the next block, if not indented properly.

If indented properly then Forzaa's answer is the answer otherwise the code is useless anyway and needs to be debugged.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense when you put it that way.
Spyder does have a "Fix indentation" option, though every time i tried using it, nothing happened whatsoever

Comment: **Wing IDE does block indentation** very efficiently and it is a feature I miss at Spyder

Answer (score 2):

First I will just reconfirm what has been said above, that python is ambiguous about what should be the correct indent. Unfortunately as coming from Matlab I also like Ctrl-I.

Though just check on how Tab and Shift-Tab work in practice, they did a little better than I expected. When I ended up having 2 tabs too much after rearranging code, one Shift-tab brought it back to proper position.