# how to indent the code block in Python IDE: Spyder?

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

Is there any shortcut key in Spyder python IDE to indent the code block?
For example, Like `ctr+[` in Matlab, I want to indent the code block together.

Comment: `<tab>` on selection ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spyder in particular, but many IDEs will let you select all the lines you want to indent and *then* press tab; this will indent all of the select lines. Or use Shift-tab to un-indent. Here is a link to the documentation: https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/overview.html . It says that in the preferences dialogue box, one can find keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37181491/spyder-ide-automatic-indentation/38996684

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Select your code and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> for indent and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to un-indent.

or go to *Edit -> Indent/Unindent*

*Edit section* also contains some other tools for editing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Spyder 4 select the lines and then press **TAB or CTRL+]** For indent and **shift+TAB or CTRL+]** for un-indent